# Recycler View data is duplicated after doing swipeToRefresh multiple times

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am showing `Firebase` data in a `RecyclerView` and it is working fine.

I have also implemented a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and when user swipe it, it is getting latest data from `Firebase`. But whenever I swipe it more than once, it is showing duplicate values although I am clearing the `ArrayList` and also I am using `swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true)``

Here I am implementing `SwipeRefreshLayout`:

```
swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                getData();

                if (swipeRefresh.isEnabled())
                    swipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });
```

Here is my `getData()` function:

```
    public void getData() {
        pd.setTitle("Loading Data");
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();

        infoList = new ArrayList<>();
        distributorList = new ArrayList<>();

        infoList.clear();
        distributorList.clear();

        countChilds = 0;
        counter = 0;
        final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        final DatabaseReference hotelRef = rootRef.child("Orders");
        hotelRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                final String key = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                final String hotelName = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("hotelName").getValue());
                final String location = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("location").getValue());
                final String quantity = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("quantity").getValue());
                final String time = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue());

                final DatabaseReference progressRef = rootRef.child("Progress").child(key);
                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            shipment = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("shipment").getValue());
                            firstMile = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("firstMile").getValue());
                            distributor = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("distributor").getValue());
                        }
                        if (shipment.equals("1") && firstMile.equals("2") && !distributor.equals("2")) {
                            counter++;
                            Information information = new Information(key, hotelName, location, quantity, time);
                            infoList.add(information);
                            distributorList.add(distributor);

                            try {
                                adapter = new DistributorItemAdapter(infoList, distributorList, getContext(), DistributorListFragment.this);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No more Orders", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } else {
                            shipment = "";
                            distributor = "";
                            firstMile = "";
                        }

                        if (counter == 0) {
                            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                        } else
                            emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d("Database Error", databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                };
                progressRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

                countChilds++;
                if (countChilds >= dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()) {
                    if (pd.isShowing())
                        pd.dismiss();
                    if (!swipeRefresh.isEnabled())
                        swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
                    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: It is not good idea to re-set adapter. Instead, just assign the obtained data and call notifyDatasetChanged() method to inform that your data is changed. If you are sure no duplication happening then set null to release datas of the viewholder in onBindViewHolder.

Comment: where do i call notifyDatasetChanged()?

Comment: That method belongs to RecyclerView.Adapter. Which means you can call as yourAdapterInstance.notifyDataSetChanged(). Please refer to https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter

Comment: Why do you need swipe to refresh if firebase is real time?

Comment: @cutiko because when new data is added, i want to show that latest data which is not showing up automatically.

Comment: @MuhammedYalçınKuru notifyDataSetChanged() is not working :/

Comment: If you get the new data on any of the callbacks of the listener method then you dont need swipe to refresh, you need to update the adapter and use the adapter methods such as notifydatasetchange

Comment: @cutiko can you send me some reference?

Comment: Add a log on every callback, add some data on the database, if the log happens then add the data to the adapter with a log inside the adapter exposed method, if that happens then add the new data to the old data in the adapter and call notify data set changed, you don't need a reference you need debuging. If you don't know how to use an adapter, then start for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should initialize your `adapter` where you initialize your `recylerview` and `set adapter` to `recylcerView` like the following.

```
//recyclerView = findViewById.....

infoList = new ArrayList<>();
distributorList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new DistributorItemAdapter(infoList, distributorList, getContext(), DistributorListFragment.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now modify your `getData()` like below.

```
public void getData() {
  pd.setTitle("Loading Data");
  pd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
  pd.setCancelable(false);
  pd.show();

  infoList.clear();
  distributorList.clear();

  countChilds = 0;
  counter = 0;
  final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
  final DatabaseReference hotelRef = rootRef.child("Orders");
  hotelRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            final String key = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            final String hotelName = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("hotelName").getValue());
            final String location = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("location").getValue());
            final String quantity = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("quantity").getValue());
            final String time = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue());

           final DatabaseReference progressRef = rootRef.child("Progress").child(key);
           ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                       shipment = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("shipment").getValue());
                       firstMile = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("firstMile").getValue());
                       distributor = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("distributor").getValue());
                   }
                   if (shipment.equals("1") && firstMile.equals("2") && !distributor.equals("2")) {
                        counter++;
                        Information information = new Information(key, hotelName, location, quantity, time);
                         infoList.add(information);
                         distributorList.add(distributor);

                         // notify your adapter that data set is changed
                         adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

                        } else {
                            shipment = "";
                            distributor = "";
                            firstMile = "";
                        }

                        if (counter == 0) {
                            emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(null);
                        } else
                            emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        Log.d("Database Error", databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                };
                progressRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

                countChilds++;
                if (countChilds >= dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()) {
                    if (pd.isShowing())
                        pd.dismiss();
                    if (!swipeRefresh.isEnabled())
                        swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
                    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }

           //....

    });
}
```

Comment: adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); is not working, it is showing nothing in RecyclerView

Comment: that means there is no data showing in my recyclerview

Comment: it should work. if your previous(above in question) code is work. Please check carefully that you are not missing something.

Comment: my above code was working and was showing data. and was working fine but now it is showing nothing. I've used Log to check that data is coming from firebase and it is perfect except for the adapter which is not showing any data

Comment: can you propose some other solution?